# How to convert .msg file to PDF using java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, rtf, msg

I want to generate pdf file from msg file using java. Mail body format should be same. I want to go with java libraries as system where i'm going to run this code may not have outlook installed.
I have tried rtfToHtml(Reader rtf) functions provided online but it is not working properly facing format issues.
I'm looking for open source api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Rupesh, did you find a solution? Does it works also with streams instead of files?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free Java Based API Zeonpad. this library provide the api to convert msg file to pdf. Refer http://www.zeonpad.com/app/zeonpad-pdf-api.html

**Example:**

```
OutlookToPdf outlookToPdf = new OutlookToPdf();
OutlookToPdf.convert("D:\\input.msg", "D:\\output.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vivek. It works if outlook is installed on system. but if outlook is not installed it won't work. Please correct me if im wrong. Any suggestion.. Thanks again.